# NetBeans 11 and Encoding characters

Tags: netbeans

Now I download **Apache NetBeans 11** and after that, I CLONE my Git PHP Repository to Windows Folder, If I open HTML files via Notepad, everything is ok, but when I open it via NetBeans, I got wrong characters interpretation like this:

**BAD**

```
<a href="{{path('homepage')}}">Ăšvod</a>
```

**RIGHT**

```
<a href="{{path('homepage')}}">Úvod</a>
```

How can I solve it to use UTF8? When I open a file in example via PSPad Editor I see the encoding is UTF8, but the format is UNIX, not DOS, maybe this cause a problem

**Edit:**

When I use Netbeans 8.2 Characters are ok

Any sugestions?